# Grant a specific user to modify a specific table rows

Tags: mysql

For security reason, I don't like the auditor has the privilege to modify all the rows of the table. So I tried:

```
GRANT UPDATE audit_comment ON cgis TO auditor IDENTIFIED BY 'audit@TE';
```

But it failed

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'audit_comment ON cgis TO auditor IDENTIFIED BY 'audit@TE'' at line 1
```

I've googled a lot, but I couldn't find the answer, maybe mysql doesn't allow us to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify privileges on rows, just on columns. Check the syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges)
You need something like
`GRANT UPDATE (audit_comment) ON db_name.cgis TO 'auditor'@'host_name'`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using views instead of tables which can be used to restrict access to only a certain type of rows. Here is a very basic example

**PICTURES table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pictures_t
(
   id      INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   public  BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

**PICTURES view:**

```
CREATE VIEW pictures_v
AS
SELECT 
   P.*
FROM pictures_t AS P
WHERE
   P.public = TRUE
ORDER BY id;
```

**Create Users:**

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON db.pictures_t TO 'god'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'heaven';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON db.pictures_v TO 'satan'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'hell';
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider using a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html).  Have the procedure update the rows, and set it to use SQL SECURITY DEFINER.  Within the stored procedure, you can include whatever validation you need, and revoke the access to modify rows from the person or people you want to limit it on.  It's a bit more complicated, but it's the only way I know of to limit the kind of access you're looking for.

Comment: Apparently they've removed the article from their site.  Why, I have no idea, but Google can't find a current copy of it there any more.  Here's a link to it from the Internet Archive.  http://bit.ly/IE9dHW  There's also a mirror here: http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/mysql/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html